# Single error message for Zend multiCheckbox element insead of multiple

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I have the multiCheckbox element on my form with the common callback validator.

Validator works ok, but error message contains duplicated strings, separated by semicolon instead of single message. If 2 checkboxes selected - the 2 error messages, if 4 - 4 error messages and so on.

Do you know how to modify the code in order to show only one single error message instead of duplicates?

```
 $rolesElement = $form->getElement('role_ids');
 $rolesElement->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_Callback(function ($value) use ($rolesElement, $administrator) {
        if( *magicHere* ){
            $rolesElement->clearErrorMessages();
            $rolesElement->setErrorMessages(array('blablabla!'));

            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }));
```

Comment: Post your Code. Also, Are you using Zend Forms or Normal HTML Forms?

Comment: It's a simple Zend form. Looks like I should create my own custom validator instead of callback validator in order to avoid multiple addError method call.

Comment: The code has been added.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use **`setMessages()`** method of the Validator class you are using to set Custom Error Messages.

**Here is my Code**

```
$emailIdValidator->setMessages(array(
            Zend_Validate_EmailAddress::DOT_ATOM => $this->coreUtils->getApplicationMessages("EMAIL_ERROR"),
            Zend_Validate_EmailAddress::INVALID => $this->coreUtils->getApplicationMessages("EMAIL_ERROR"),
            Zend_Validate_EmailAddress::INVALID_FORMAT => $this->coreUtils->getApplicationMessages("EMAIL_ERROR"),
            Zend_Validate_EmailAddress::INVALID_HOSTNAME => $this->coreUtils->getApplicationMessages("EMAIL_ERROR"),
            Zend_Validate_EmailAddress::INVALID_LOCAL_PART => $this->coreUtils->getApplicationMessages("EMAIL_ERROR"),
            Zend_Validate_EmailAddress::INVALID_MX_RECORD => $this->coreUtils->getApplicationMessages("EMAIL_ERROR"),
            Zend_Validate_EmailAddress::INVALID_SEGMENT => $this->coreUtils->getApplicationMessages("EMAIL_ERROR"),
            Zend_Validate_EmailAddress::LENGTH_EXCEEDED => $this->coreUtils->getApplicationMessages("EMAIL_ERROR"),
            Zend_Validate_EmailAddress::QUOTED_STRING => $this->coreUtils->getApplicationMessages("EMAIL_ERROR"),
        ));
```

Comment: This is validation messages for Zend_Validate_EmailAddress. They are not compatible with Callback validator.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $form = new Zend_Form ();
    $form->addElement ('MultiCheckbox', 'name', array (
        'label' => 'test',
        'multioptions' => array (
            1 => 'fake',
            65 => 'dsa',
            165 => 'dsa22'
        )
    ));

    $form->name->addValidator ('Callback', true, array (
        'callback' => array (
            $this,
            'val'
        ),
        'messages' => array (
            'callbackValue' => 'Error in here'
        )
    ));
```

In this case, the validating function should not add any error messages. Just a boolean value.

```
function val ($value, $values)
{
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by the creation of my own custom validator based on Zend_Validate.

Comment: This answer does not answer the question.

Comment: The problem was with multiple call of addError method.

Comment: Also the basic Callback method has strange behaviour with translations (probably it's not general problem, project-dependent). So the solution with my own validator works fine. Thanks for help.